# How to show $\Psi: E \to E$ is a contraction w.r.t the norm $\| f \| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} e^{-2Lx} |f(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

I'm doing this exercise in functional analysis:

> Let $E = \mathcal C^0 ([0,1], \mathbb R)$, $L \ge 1$, and $\mathcal F: [0,1] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  be a continuous function which is $L$-Lipschitz with respect to the second variable. We define $\Psi: E \to E$ by $$\forall f \in E,\forall x \in [0,1]:\Psi (f)(x) = \int_0^x \mathcal F (t, f(t)) \, \mathrm{d} t$$ Furthermore, we define a norm $\| \cdot\|$ on $E$ by $$\forall f \in E:\| f \| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} e^{-2Lx} |f(x)|$$ Prove that $\Psi$ is a contraction.

---

Below is my attempt in which I'm stuck at showing

1. $\bar x \in [0,1]$
2. $\Phi$ attains maximum at $\bar x$

Could you please shed me some light to finish the proof? Thank you so much!

---

**My attempt:**

Let $f,g \in E$. We have $$\begin{aligned}
|\Psi (f)(x) - \Psi (g)(x) | &= \left | \int_0^x \Big ( \mathcal F (t, f(t)) - \mathcal F (t, g(t)) \Big) \, \mathrm{d} t \right | \\
&\le \int_0^x \left |  \mathcal F (t, f(t)) - \mathcal F (t, g(t)) \right | \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&\le L \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t \end{aligned}$$

It follows that $$e^{-2Lx}|\Psi (f)(x) - \Psi (g)(x) |  \le L e^{-2Lx} \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$

Consider the map $\Phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $$\Phi (x) = L e^{-2Lx} \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$

My goal is to find the maximum of $\Phi$. We have $$\begin{aligned} \Phi'(x) &= -2L^2 e^{-2Lx} \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t + L e^{-2Lx} | f(x)- g(x) | \\ &= L e^{-2Lx} \left (| f(x)- g(x) | - 2L \int_0^x | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t \right )\end{aligned}$$

If $\bar x$ is a critical point, then $\Phi'(\bar x) = 0$ and consequently $$\frac{1}{2} | f(\bar x)- g(\bar x) | = L \int_0^{\bar x} | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$

Then $$\Phi(\bar x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-2L \bar x} | f(\bar x)- g(\bar x) | \le \frac{1}{2} \|f-g\|$$

As such, my proof is done if I show that

1. $\bar x \in [0,1]$
2. $\Phi$ attains maximum at $\bar x$

Comment: If $\Phi$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ then there exists $\bar x\in[0,1]$ such that $\Phi(\bar x)=\max_{y\in[0,1]}\Phi(y)$ since $\Phi([0,1])$ is compact. Or are you needing to find $\bar x$ explicitly?

Comment: Hi @Math1000, I'm trying to prove that if $\Phi$ attains maximum at $\bar x$ then $\Phi'(\bar x) = 0$. But I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: Hi @Math1000, let $\bar x$ be the critical point of $\Phi$, i.e. $\Phi'(\bar x)=0$. Then $\Phi$ attains maximum either at $0$, $\bar x$, or $1$. We have $$\Phi (0)=0$$ and $$\Phi(\bar x)= \frac{1}{2} e^{-2L \bar x} | f(\bar x)- g(\bar x) |$$ and $$\Phi(1) = L e^{-2L} \int_0^1 | f(t)- g(t) | \, \mathrm{d} t$$ Clearly, $\Phi(\bar x) \ge \Phi(0)$ and $\Phi(1) \ge \Phi(0)$. I'm stuck at comparing $\Phi(\bar x)$ and $\Phi(1)$. Could you please give me some hints?